# Embedded C, and AVR GCC compilation issue with multiple definitions

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor, interrupt-handling, avr-gcc

It seems that my compiler does not willing to build the firmware in `stepper_motor.c` and as you can see below, it throws this error, which I am unable to solve.

I have created a `stepper_motor.c` source where all my functions and variables are placed, and a `stepper_motor.h` header where all the `#define`s and function prototypes are. In `main.c` I just include the `stepper_motor.h` header and use the functions. As you can see from shell log data, it does not compile and tells that 4 x variables are defined multiple times. Those ones are used in ISR() routine for a timer, so they need to be also volatile.

Any information would be highly appreciated on this issue.

this is my main.c includes: --------

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <Hardware_Bay.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <USART.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <scale16.h>
#include <stepper_motor.h>

const uint8_t motor_Phases[] = {
    (1 << COIL_B1),                             // full step
    (1 << COIL_B1) | (1 << COIL_A2),            // half step
    (1 << COIL_A2),                             // full step
    (1 << COIL_A2) | (1 << COIL_B2),            // half step
    (1 << COIL_B2),                             // full step
    (1 << COIL_B2) | (1 << COIL_A1),            // etc..
    (1 << COIL_A1),
    (1 << COIL_A1) | (1 << COIL_B1),
};

volatile uint8_t stepPhase = 0;
volatile uint16_t stepCounter = 0;
volatile int8_t direction = FORWARD;

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {                    // Timer/Counter-0 Compare match interrupt vector enable
    stepPhase += direction;                 // take step in right direction
    stepPhase &= 0b00000111;                // keep the stepPhase in range (0 - 7)
    STEPPER_PORT = motor_Phases[stepPhase]; // write phase out to motor COIL-1 A/B
    HALL_PORT = motor_Phases[stepPhase];    // write phase out to motor COIL-2 A/B
    stepCounter ++;
}
```

------------------------------header file -----------------------------------------------

```
#ifndef STEPPER_MOTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define STEPPER_MOTOR_H_INCLUDED

#endif // STEPPER_MOTOR_H_INCLUDED

#define FORWARD           1                      
#define BACKWARD         -1
#define TURN              200  

#define MAX_DELAY         255                                                  
#define MIN_DELAY         10                                                      
#define ACCELERATION      16                                        

#define RAMP_STEPS        (MAX_DELAY - MIN_DELAY) / ACCELERATION

void stepperDrive(uint8_t number_of_steps, uint8_t delay);

void trapezoidDrive_Stepper(int16_t number_of_steps);
```

```
PS D:\Users\Arhitect\Documents\C_Programs\Physalis_Banshee\Physalis_GEO_version_3.6> make flash
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,Physalis_GEO_version_3.6.map -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega1284p fuse.o main.o stepper_motor.o USART.o  -o Physalis_GEO_version_3.6.elf
stepper_motor.o: In function `stepperDrive':
D:\Users\Arhitect\Documents\C_Programs\Physalis_Banshee\Physalis_GEO_version_3.6/stepper_motor.c:50: multiple definition of `stepCounter'
main.o:(.bss.stepCounter+0x0): first defined here
stepper_motor.o:(.data.direction+0x0): multiple definition of `direction'
main.o:(.data.direction+0x0): first defined here
stepper_motor.o:(.rodata.motor_Phases+0x0): multiple definition of `motor_Phases'
main.o:(.rodata.motor_Phases+0x0): first defined here
stepper_motor.o: In function `stepperDrive':
D:\Users\Arhitect\Documents\C_Programs\Physalis_Banshee\Physalis_GEO_version_3.6/stepper_motor.c:50: multiple definition of `stepPhase'
main.o:(.bss.stepPhase+0x0): first defined here
make: *** [Physalis_GEO_version_3.6.elf] Error 1
PS D:\Users\Arhitect\Documents\C_Programs\Physalis_Banshee\Physalis_GEO_version_3.6>
```

Comment: You are not telling us the whole story. It's as if you are including main.o twice in the linker parameter list (or maybe main.c once and main.o once?), but without seeing your makefile, it's impossible to tell. It doesn't look like an include guard problem to me. Oh, and please try and make that error message easier to read!

Comment: One of the error messages says that `stepCounter` is defined in `main.o` and in `stepper_motor.o`, which derive from `main.c` and `stepper_motor.c`. We can see `stepCounter` is defined in `main.c` because you showed us the source. But you did not show us `stepper_motor.c`. When asking a question like this on Stack Overflow, you should include a [mre]. However, the error message is clear: You also define `stepCounter` in `stepper_motor.c`. Remove the duplicate definition. If `stepCounter` needs to be accessible in multiple source files, put a non-definition declaration in a header file.

Comment: What are the contents of `stepper_motor.c`?

Comment: Your header include guards are wrong: the `#endif` should be the last line of the header file.

Comment: And where is `main()`?

Comment: It seems you've declared the same global variables both in `stepper_motor.c` and `main.c`. Try to declare as `extern` those in the `main`. I.E. `extern volatile uint8_t stepPhase;` then you have to assign the value 0 at the beginning of the `main` function:  `stepPhase = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the error messages tell you all you need to know - you have defined these symbols in two places - main.c and setpper_motor.c.

You have defined `stepCounter` at line 50 of stepper_motor.c and also as shown in main.c.  Similarly for `stepPase` and `motor_Phases`.

- If they are independent and should not be visible externally then
  both should be declared `static` so that they are visible only in
  their respective translation units.
- If it is intended that the symbol refers to the they are the *same* object, then one of them needs to be declared `extern` to indicate to the compiler its type and name, but that it is *defined* elsewhere..
- If they are independent but "need" to be global (because you cannot
  think of a better solution), then they cannot have the same name.
- If you do not reference them in main.c, then they should in any event be removed from there.  It seems odd that you would define them here when they clearly relate to stepper motor control and should probably be encapsulated in stepper_motor.c.

Avoiding the use of globals in the fist place is a much better solution see https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/

Comment: the issue was resolved, It was related to "extern" as you proposed already.Declaration of variables in source file. was also twice.  I did not work much with modular programs, in C and therefore was hard to spot the mistakes. 
David